# Spring maven build: invalid entry size (expected 2 but got 1 bytes)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

```
          Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring- 
           boot-maven-plugin:1.5.14.RELEASE:repackage (default) 
       on project OptimizeService: zip END header not found -> 


               Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.14.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project OptimizeService: zip END header not found -> [Help 1]
```

Not sure if anyone has any insight on what to look into for this? Seems like a pretty vague error. Project runs locally okay but "run as maven build" in eclipse comes up with this

Comment: BTW: Which Java version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you local cache (`$HOME/.m2/repository`) is corrupted based on Network issues or a like. The only clean solution is to delete the local cache and configure the checksum policy in your [`settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) and afterwards rebuild your project.

I hope you are using a repository manager. If not start to use one.

Details can be found [here](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/).

Comment: So I tried deleting the repo folder and letting it download the dependency's again, still the same issue

Comment: Have you turned on checksum policy? Are you using a repository manager ?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to 1.5.15-RELEASE solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding these lines into pom.xml,

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Note: Update your maven version accordingly.